# Tracking a Predefined Curve in a Series of Images

Tags: image-processing, edge-detection, tracking

I have a series of images. I want to be able to draw a curve on the image and track the curve in the series. For example, in the figure below, the left image illustrates the original image at time `0` and the one on the right is the curve I want to track in the next images in later times $t>0$. In fact, the edges that are marked as red change with time. In other words, the region, whose a portion of its boundary is shown in the figure, gets enlarged and shrunken in the subsequent images and I want to be able to track this.

Could someone kindly introduce me to one of the methods that is used to track a predefined curves according to the movement of the boundary which is the closest to it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my experience, I have successfully utilized [Leo Grady's Random Walks method](http://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~nray1/CMPUT615/MRF/grady2006random.pdf) for this. The code is also available [here](http://cns.bu.edu/~lgrady/software.html). It works very well and can easily be made to run in real-time depending on the contour and image size. You could watch the video from my implementation [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LXnqfDa5Fc8&list=UUMSqZYDAmbiaAhyvLPJGhsg). Note that though, it might perfom differently than the original.

Comment: So, you start off with drawing a curve and then the method takes care of tracking it in other images?

Comment: That's right. Two curves actually. One for the pixels outside the region, one for the inside. The rest is taken care of. It is a binary labeling and thus the problem is binary segmentation. However, this is a tracking method, which will let you to follow it through the sequence.

Comment: Fantastic. This is what I am looking for. The video link you provided is very helpful. What function in the toolbox should be called for this task?

Comment: Well a series of functions but yes the toolbox would greatly assist you.

Comment: Would you provide an example?

Comment: It is in the toolbox you download already.